# GORM ASSOCIATION EXPLANATION

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I need help creating association among Domain Classes. I have three domains: User, News, Comments. A User can make many comments on many news. A news can have many comments from many users.

I am having a big problem implementing this association in GORM.

[image: Gorm Assocaition]

I want to be able for a user to add comments to a news item. The comment should have a reference to the user who made it. And  a news item should have a list of all its comments.

Domain Classes:

```
class User {
    String nickName
    String password
    Date dateCreated
    static hasMany = [users : User, comments : Comment]
    static hasOne = [profile : Profile]
    //static belongsTo = [comments : Comment]

    static constraints = {
        profile nullable: true
    }
}

class News {

    String webTitle
    String webPublicationDate;
    String trailText;
    String webUrl;
    String thumbnail;
    String webId;
    static hasMany = [tags : Tag, comments  : Comment]

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Comment {
    //static belongsTo = [news : News, user : User]
    String content
    int likes
    int disLikes
    Date lastUpdated
    static hasOne = [user: User, news:  News]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

IntegrationTests include:

```
 void "A user can add to a post's comments"(){
    given: "An existing user"
    def newUser = new User(nickName: 'nickName', password: 'password').save(failOnError: true, flush : true)

    and: "A comment and a news"
    def news = new NewsItem(webTitle: 'I Love Hillary', webPublicationDate: new Date(),
            trailText: 'Hillary can change America', webUrl: 'http:google.com', webId: '4', thumbnail: 'image')

    when: 'A user adds comment to post'
    def comm = new Comment(content: "Hillary cant be president", user: newUser, newsItem: news)
    newUser.addToComments(comm)
    news.addToComments(comm)

    then: "NewsItem must have some comments"
    news.comments.size() == 1
    news.comments[0].user == newUser
    newUser.comments.size() == 1
    comm.user == newUser
    news.comments != null
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "my tests are failing" - how are they failing? please add your failing asserts, stacktraces, ...

Comment: I have provided the test result. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather slightly change your domain classes:

```
class User {
    String nickName
    String password
    Date dateCreated
    static hasMany = [users : User, comments : Comment]
    static hasOne = [profile : Profile]

    static constraints = {
        profile nullable: true
    }
}

class Communicate { //because News could possibly create troubles during generating controller or test classes (it's the same as singular and plural)
    String webId; 
    String webTitle
    String webPublicationDate;
    String trailText;
    String webUrl;
    String thumbnail;
    static hasMany = [tags : Tag, comments  : Comment]

    static constraints = {
    }

}

class Comment {
    static belongsTo = [user: User, communicate: Communicate] //read more about it: http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html
    String content
    int likes
    int disLikes
    Date lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

After these changes you should probably recreate these tables (or create-drop full db if it's still in dev stage).

Moreover by adding `belongsTo` statements to **Comment** you should fix your tests (`user` and 'communicate' properties will be neccessary on create-time):

```
def comm = new Comment(content: "Hillary cant be president", user:user, communicate:news)
```

Comment: Hi brother, thanks for your answer. I should have mention this in my post. The news has no relation to a user. The news is a separate entity on its own. It will fetched from a restful api. And then displayed to users. User can then add their comments to these news-items. Please update your answer. Thank you

Comment: Moreover, the reason why I was keeping the webId from the restful api. I implemented this to make sure, I don't have duplicate news-items in my database. The webId is a unique field. It's purpose is just to prevent duplicates. I usually fetch the latest 10 items. And those who are repeated will raise an exception till ones that are new

Comment: Thanks. Creating associations is so difficult for me. Allow me to ask more. A comment belongs to the user who made it and also belongs to the NewsItem on which it has been made. Shouldn't the belongsTo point to both of them?

Comment: In fact: yes! You can do this be duo belongsTo. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yet to test. Someone is watching wrestling on my laptop.

Comment: So by creating comment with an instance of a user and a news will persist it through all. Because of the belongsTo, right? I have read the documentation. But doing is different from reading

Comment: Yes, `addTo` should not be neccessary anymore.

Comment: I hope my vote on your answer is public. First I was told I don't have enough points. But is showing here

Comment: Yes, it's visible. If everything will work smooth you can also accept my answer.

Comment: This is a very necessary skill. Where can I master it. I have being reading Grails in Action along with the documentation. But this is always a problem. Can't get it to be perfect.

Comment: Just practise by writing your own and reading someone else code (for example here, on SO).

Comment: I have done what is here, still getting **java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method size() on null object** at here: `news.comments.size() == 1`

Comment: check the new test, it works now. But i have to call addToComments() explicitly, either wise a NullPointerException is raised